# Add Jar file to Jupyter notebook - : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver

Tags: pyspark, jar, jupyter-notebook, teradata

I got a pyspark script which was run by using this bash script:
[image]

Now I am running the pyspark script on jupyter notebook. I added the teradata jar like this:
[image]

But when I tried to use"spark.read.jdbc" later to run a query to retrieve teradata data, I got this error:
[image]

May I know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars /jar/path/ pyspark-shell'
```